# Accessing points inside structs inside unions - C

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have the following data structures

```
struct a_str {
    union {
        struct {
            struct c_str *c;
        } b_str;        

        struct {
            int i;
        } c_str;
    };

}

struct c_str {
    struct d_str;
}

struct d_str {
    int num;
}
```

I am trying to access num in struct d_str. For some reason I keep on getting a segmentation fault.

```
struct a_str *a = init_a(); //assume memory allocation and init is ok.
a->b_str.c->d_str.num = 2;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `//assume memory allocation and init is ok` If you're getting a segfault I'm going to assume that's not the case.

Comment: Could you also show us `init_a()`.

Comment: The inference is that your pointers are NOT initialised

Comment: if you knew what the problem is, you wouldn't be posting this.. so you shouldn't try to make us assume that nay part of yoru code is good.  Since you don't know what bad code looks like (otherwise you would have seen it)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not allocating memory for `a->b_str.c` in your `init()` function, that may be reason that   `a->b_str.c` is pointing a garbage location and segmentation fault is due to accessing memory that is not allocated - an illegal memory operation.
If `init()` function is correct, there should not be any problem (syntax-wise your code is correct).

Below I have suggested `inti()` function that will allocated memory for your nested structure correctly (read comments).

```
struct a_str *init()
{
    struct a_str *ret  = malloc(sizeof(struct a_str)); // memory for `struct a_str`
    struct c_str *cptr = malloc(sizeof(struct c_str)); // memory for inner struct
    ret->b_str.c = cptr;  //assigning valid memory address to ret->b_str.c 
    return ret;
}
```

Below is the `main()` code with steps for deallocate/free() dynamically allocated memory.

```
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    struct a_str *ret = init();    
    ret->b_str.c->d.num = 5;
    printf("%d\n", ret->b_str.c->d.num);


    //Make sure to free the memory allocated through malloc
    free(ret->b_str.c);  // 1 first free in struct 
    free(ret);           // in reverse order of allocation
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: correct, add a code for free() also, because OP may have memory-leak in his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct a_str *a = init_a();
```

My guess: Your init_a function

- is allocating the a_str pointer
- is not allocating the a->b_str.c pointer

Since a->b_str.c is not allocated, when you want to access it, a segfault occur

**EDIT :**

Second guess: Your init_a function

- is allocating the a_str pointer
- is allocating the a->b_str.c pointer
- is initializing the a->c_str.i integer value

By initializing c_str.i value, it erase the b_str.c value Since it share the same location (it is a union).

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your pointer "c" if it has been initialized